# Manipulating CSS file programmatically

Tags: css

Is there any library available around to manipulate CSS files like the Hpricot for HTML/XML etc.

I have a lot of CSS files for different theme, and sometime for a minor change I need to open each CSS file and make that change.

I want to do it programmatically, preferably in Ruby.

Thanks,
Imran

Comment: By manipulating I mean, I can select a class and change its styles. Add, delete new classes etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [less](http://lesscss.org/) or [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/)?  They probably aren't quite what you're looking for--but they are both languages that compile to CSS and use cleaner syntax and other benefits like variables.

Comment: They look great. But I am still looking for some library for this, as I have a lot of existing css files to deal with.